# Dependency Injection when nesting Views in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am attempting to nest Views, which use MVVM and hence have a ViewModel injected into them.
The code behind for the OuterView as well as the xaml for the InnerView are not really relevant, so I am leaving them, as well as all functionality, out for brevity. The Views and ViewModels are registered as Services, so DI should work.
The structure is as follows:

```cs
public partial class {
   public InnerView(InnerViewModel viewModel){
       BindingContext = viewModel;
       InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Example.Views"
             x:Class="Example.Views.OuterView"
             x:DataType="viewModels:OuterViewModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout name="InnerViewWrapper">
        <pages:InnerView/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This gives me the error "Type 'InnerView' is not usable as an object element because it [...] does not not define a parameterless constructor [...]". This makes sense, so I started just adding the View in my code-behind.

```cs
StockHistoryGraph? view = Handler?.MauiContext?.Services.GetServices<StockHistoryGraph>().FirstOrDefault(defaultValue: default);
if (view is not null) 
    InnerViewWrapper.Add(view);
```

This however seems quite tedious, so my question is:
Is there a way to use DI on a View which is declared in a xaml file?

Comment: How did you add ```InnerViewModel``` into the DI?

Comment: usually when you have a nested view, you want it to inherit it's `BindingContext` from the parent, not use a fixed context

Comment: Also personally I am not a fan of creating Views through DI they just make things messy and your builder heavier for no apparent reason

Comment: [ServiceHelper class is another useful approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76635084/199364). (On a question that is marked as a duplicate of this one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three ways to fix InnerView so that it works with a parameterless constructor.
First two involve setting BindingContext in code-behind.
Third avoids needing BindingContext.
In all solutions, InnerView MUST NOT have XAML that sets BindingContext.

---

**FIX #1: `new InnerViewModel` instead of DI:**

```cs
public InnerView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new InnerViewModel();
}
```

---

**FIX #2: Explicitly resolve the service (works even if InnerViewModel needs DI-injected parameters):**

```cs
public InnerView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<InnerViewModel>();
}
```

---

**FIX #3: Code InnerView so it accesses its properties WITHOUT setting BindingContext:**

```xml
  <SomeElement SomeAttribute="{Binding MyProperty, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" />
  <-- OPTIONAL -->
  <SomeElement SomeAttribute="{Binding VM.MyProperty2, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

```cs
public partial class InnerView : ContentView
{
    // OPTIONAL: If you really want a view model for this custom component
    // (usually not needed; just put properties in "this",
    //  as seen with "MyProperty".)
  private InnerViewModel VM { get; set; }

  public SomeType MyProperty { get; set; }

  public InnerView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    // NO "BindingContext = ...;"

    // OPTIONAL
    VM = new InnerViewModel();
    // OR (works even if InnerViewModel has DI-injected parameters)
    VM = Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<InnerViewModel>();
  }
}

// OPTIONAL
public class InnerViewModel
{
    public SomeType2 MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

---

**BONUS: App.Services property**

To shorten:

```
Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services
```

to:

```
App.Services
```

Ex: `... = App.Services.GetService<SomeType>();`.

Inject service provider into App's (`App.xaml.cs`) constructor,
and set a property to it:

```cs
... class App
{
    public readonly IServiceProvider Services;

    public App(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        ...

        Services = services;
    }
}
```

---

[ServiceHelper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76635084/199364) is an alternative to `App.Services`.